# ASP NET MVC Incluir Parâmetro de Url em todas as páginas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tenho uma aplicação ASP NET MVC que é multi-client e multi-user, ou seja, ela é preparada para ser utilizada por vários clientes e cada cliente pode ter vários usuários.

Inicialmente o formulário de login possui a entrada de texto para o código do cliente. Porém desejo realizar algum roteamento para o usuário possa informar o código de cliente diretamente na URL, sei que utilizando o roteamento padrão eu consigo obter este código pegando o valor do parâmetro id no controller, porém isto funciona apenas na primeira página se for realizado algum redirecionamento eu não consigo pegar esta informação.

Como devo implementar isto? abaixo minha classe RouteConfig:

```
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {controller = "Acesso", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você poderia colocar algum exemplo? o que entendi é que você gostaria de ter algum mapeamento do tipo: `{cliente}/{controller}/{action}/{id}` onde cliente é o ID do cliente referente a aquela seção.

Comment: Essa é uma implementação bem tranquila para fazer, só cuide com a segurança @Julio, aonde alguém pode ir lá e trocar esse "id"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supondo que você queira uma url nesse padrão:

```
/empresaId/clientes/clienteId
```

Que poderia ser traduzido para:

```
/1/clientes/10
```

Você pode criar uma rota:

```
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("Empresa", "{empresa}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {controller = "Acesso", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
        }
    }
```

Definir o parâmetro da empresa no controller:

```
public class Clientes : Controller 
{
    // rota: /1/clientes/10
    public ActionResult Index(int empresa, int id) 
    { 
    }

    // rota: /1/clientes/editar/10
    public ActionResult Editar(int empresa, int id) 
    { 
    }
}
```

Criar uma session para o id da empresa no login:

```
var empresaId = 1;
Session.Add("empresa", empresaId);
```

Para então criar os links, você faz uso da session ao passar o parâmetro da empresa:

```
@Html.Action("index", "clientes", new { empresa = Session["empresa"] })
```

ou

```
@Html.ActionLink("editar", "clientes", new { empresa = Session["empresa"] })
```

ou

```
@Url.Action("index", "clientes", new { empresa = Session["empresa"] })
```

Comment: Usaria um helper para esses links aí =D só isso para add

Comment: Eu utilizaria um `alias` único para cara cliente, assim a url para o cliente ficaria mais amigável, tipo: EmpresaA/Usuarios/5.

Answer (score 1):

Penso que algo assim poderia resolver seu problema:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "Cliente/{id}",
            new {controller = "Cliente", action = "Pesquisar", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Seu Controller ficaria assim:

```
public class Cliente : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult Pesquisar(int id) // id seria o código do cliente
    { ... }
}
```

A chamada ficaria assim:

> localhost/Cliente/12345

Comment: Ok, @Cigano, porém isto seria para a página de cliente, o que eu preciso é depois repassar este id para todas as outras páginas que acessar a partir da página cliente, ou seja, se eu criar um ActionLink por exemplo, eu quero que o controller de destino já venha com o parâmetro id carregado

Comment: @JulioBorges Isso tem que ser necessariamente por rota ou poderia ser usando o contexto da Sessão?

Comment: acredito que pode ser por meio do contexto também, o iuristona ilustrou a utilização do contexto em uma resposta, acredito que utilizando o contexto da sessão resolva. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: @JulioBorges Que rápido. Mal posso ver seus movimentos.

Comment: kkkk to aqui monitorando a questão e alterando as classes. Vlw